# OpenVPN Site to Site client on raspbian

Tags: raspbian

I have two offices connected to each other using pfSense and OpenVPN. In the main office, OpenVPN is used as the server and in the branch office, OpenVPN as the client. Both LAN has visibility of the other one.

Now, the pfSense of the branch office must be replaced by a Raspberry Pi. Is it possible to configure OpenVPN in Raspbian to do Site 2 Site VPN with the main office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have solved my problem. Here are the steps:

1. Connect to my server pfSense via SSH and open the openvpn.conf file.
2. Copy entire content to openvpn.conf file in my raspberry Pi.
3. Invert the network configuration (local lan and remote lan)
4. Configure openvpn to connect at startup.

Voila! Everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes

The pi is pretty much link any other linux system in this regard. It's difficult to give further advice without knowing more details of your setup.

Comment: The main office uses pfSense firewall, which includes OpenVPN. It is configured as Peer to Peer (shared key), UDP protocol, over 1194 port. The encryption is AES-128-CBC adn auth digest is SHA1 160bit. The main office lan is 192.168.0.0/24 and the branch office lan is 192.186.1.0/124. The IPv4 tunnel network is 192.168.168.0/24.

Comment: Doesn't sound massively difficult to set up. I would suggest trying it and if you get stuck either editing your question or posting a seperate question with more information on where you got stuck. Take the setup a step at a time, first get the VPN tunnel up and running, then worry about routing so that the networks can see each other.

Comment: I have done this steps:

1-Edit this file: nano /etc/sysctl.conf
2-Uncomment this line: net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
3-sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf

4-Install openvpn: sudo apt-get install openvpn
5-Create a conf file: sudo nano /etc/openvpn/vpn.conf

6-Edit this file: nano /etc/default/openvpn
7-Uncomment this line: AUTOSTART=all

8-Run: sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE

9- Run: sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
sudo /etc/init.d/iptables-persistent save
sudo /etc/init.d/iptables-persistent reload

Comment: Now my problem resides in the conf file. I want to use static.key, shared between server (192.168.0.0 / 24) and the branch office (192.168.1.1 / 24). Please, can you show me an example of it?

Comment: @Xuti you mean TLS key? There's [an official step-by-step guide](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/78-static-key-mini-howto.html)